Is there a way to test Google Maps Static API beta for new style change?
I saw the default map styles for the APIs are changing, specifically the Maps Static API and NOT using the cloud-based map styling. In the email it states August 2024 it will be available, but when you click on the Static Maps API docs it states "All map styles will be automatically updated in March 2025"
My questions:

Is there a way to test an "alpha" or "beta" Maps Static API?
Does anyone have the actual date when the default styles (JSON-styling) will change - August 2024 or Mar 2025?

I looked at documentation and the google announcement page but could not find a solution


There is no alpha or beta versions of the Static Maps API

The notes on the 'New map style' page say "Between May 2024 and March 18, 2025, Google Maps Platform will update the default map style for the following APIs and SDKs.".


The table underneath lists the different dates for each of the different Google Maps products which says August 2024 for Maps Static API.
So the default will change from August.
